# array_push into an existing key

Tags: php, arrays

So I have been trying to push an array into an array, but it ends up creating it seperately. Not really sure how to phrase it, but below is the php code:

```
function build_embed() {

    $output = array(
        "username" => "Form Username",
        "description" => "Form Description",
        "tts" => false,
        "embeds" => [
            [
                "title" => "Form Title",
                "type" => "rich",
                "fields" => []
            ]
        ]
    );

    foreach ( $this->inputs as $val ) :

        $id = $val['id'];
        $label = $val['label'];

        $newfields = [
            "name" => $label,
            "value" => $id,
            "inline" => false
        ];

        array_push($output['embeds']['fields'], $newfields);

    endforeach;

    return $output;
}
```

Output of the array:

```
array(4) { 
    ["username"]=> string(13) "Form Username" 
    ["description"]=> string(16) "Form Description" 
    ["tts"]=> bool(false) 
    ["embeds"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["title"]=> string(10) "Form Title" 
            ["type"]=> string(4) "rich" 
            ["fields"]=> array(0) { } 
        } 
        ["fields"]=> NULL 
    } 
}
```

Should be like:

```
array(4) { 
    ["username"]=> string(13) "Form Username" 
    ["description"]=> string(16) "Form Description" 
    ["tts"]=> bool(false) 
    ["embeds"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["title"]=> string(10) "Form Title" 
            ["type"]=> string(4) "rich" 
            ["fields"]=> array("name" => "Test","value" => "Test","inline" => false) { } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Since you're pushing in a loop, what do you expect `fields` to be for multiple inputs? You can't have duplicate keys in an associative array.

Comment: The output you show can't come from the code you posted. That would come from `array_push($output['embeds'], $newfields)`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't come from that, either. It comes from `$output['embeds']['fields'] = null;`

Comment: From that I get array(4) { ["username"]=> string(13) "Form Username" ["description"]=> string(16) "Form Description" ["tts"]=> bool(false) ["embeds"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(10) "Form Title" ["type"]=> string(4) "rich" ["fields"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Question" ["value"]=> string(8) "question" ["inline"]=> bool(false) } } }

Im trying to get it inside the fields [], and there will be multiple inputs

Comment: You need `fields` to be a 2-dimensional array so you can have multiple `name/value/inline` nested arrays. The code you posted does that.

Comment: Do you intend to have just one or multiple `embeds`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have defined `embeds` as a multidimensional array with one element array ([see the array structure here](https://3v4l.org/KqNbb)), so you would push onto the first element of `embeds` which is `0` and then `fields`:

```
array_push($output['embeds'][0]['fields'], $newfields);
```

However this is the more common and practical way:

```
$output['embeds'][0]['fields'][] = $newfields;
```

If it were defined like this, it would work with the current code:

```
    "embeds" => [
            "title" => "Form Title",
            "type" => "rich",
            "fields" => []
    ]
```

Or:

```
$output['embeds']['fields'][] = $newfields;
```

Comment: This won't create the desired result, it will just nest the associative array an extra level further.

Comment: Yes just saw I had a mixup, 1min.

Comment: It's actually `array_push($output['embeds'][0]['fields'], $newfields);` - the index goes right after `embeds` to pick up the first element of it

Comment: Thinking again, the attribution should be just `$output['embeds'][0]['fields'] = $newfields;` - because `fields` stores just one array, not an array of arrays.

Comment: No, it is adding multiple in a loop so they would just overwrite each other.